# How could Qt apply style from an external Qt Stylesheet file?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface

I would like the users to be able to customize the default look of our applications by simply loading their **OWN** Qt Style-sheet files. How do we accomplish that? Can anybody give me a head start?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Say the user have its stylesheet named `stylesheet.qss` and is located in the application folder.

You could load the style sheet when starting the application, using the -stylesheet argument :

```
myapp->stylesheet = stylesheet.qss;
```

But this require your user to know how to start an application with arguments.

What you could also do is to add a settings dialog in your app, where the user can choose a stylesheet path.

You can then open this file, load the content, and set it to your application with [QApplication::setStyleSheet()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html) :

```
 QFile file("stylesheet.qss");
 file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
 QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());

 qApp->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

Qt is providing an [example online](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) which might be helpful.

Comment: could you specify how (if possible) to use multiple stylesheets? Eg: I need to use a stylesheet for a specific layout, and another one for a second layout. In the end, is it possible to link a stylesheet to a widget, not a app?

Comment: @SKYnine did you find out how to do this? (load multiple stylesheets)

Comment: unfortunately I don't think you can. However, I found a way to deal with specific styling. Just add property to your desired object, then subclass the style in the stylesheet (like a class). Qt will go through all the standard stylesheet, then apply the overrides for specific elements matching the property name.

Comment: Man, seriously, don't use `CamelCase` on variable names, it's confusing. Especially with generic names, such as `File` or `StyleSheet`. Nobody would be surprised if those were class names.

Comment: If you want to use multiple stylesheets, read the separate files into strings and then concatenate them before setting as the styles for the application.  You will of course need to coordinate the names to not have conflicts.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica That's Pascal case.

Answer (score 3):

You just set the style sheet for the entire application based on configuration provided by the customer.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop

You could set/get this configuration from any number of places, a properties dialog in the application is probably the most natural approach.